# How to get invitee´s information who schedules event at Calendly in GTM data layer

Tags: curl, oauth, uuid

I´ve created a html site with a Calendly widget embedded to allow clients to scheduled meetings with me. Webpage is being tracked by Google Tag Manager, which is set up to listen events each time a meeting is scheduled (viewed event, date and time selected in an event, and scheduled event). On scheduling meetings, GTM data layer is receiving the information below, which includes uri (uuid event and uuid invitee). I need datalayer GTM gets the information filled in the form by the invitee (name, email, city, and all fields filled), I don´t know how to do it. I´ve tried with the code "curl --request GET " provided by calendly (see below) but it doesn´t work for me, I putted it in GTM and I tried also putting it on the webpage code, in both cases appears an error syntax, but even if syntax were fine I doubt the way I´m doing it works. Can someone help me, I´m so newbe at all this, so please explain me in a detailed way.

Information showed by Google Tag Manager (data layer) currently on scheduling events:

**API CALL**
{
event: "calendly.event_scheduled",
gtm: {uniqueEventId: 6, start: 1687210818988},
eventDetails: {
event: {
uri: "https://api.calendly.com/scheduled_events/04f8125c-e3da-4" +
"4e3-8990-9da29987d5a5"
},
invitee: {
uri: "https://api.calendly.com/scheduled_events/04f8125c-e3da-4" +
"4e3-8990-9da29987d5a5/invitees/2a44c8f6-8426-476b-bdbe-12" +
"f6c28b824c"
}
}
}

**Code I´ve tried using to get invitee´s information on GTM datalayer**

curl --request GET 
--url https://api.calendly.com/scheduled_events/uuid/invitees 
--header 'Authorization: ' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json'

[syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHzpM.png)

Comment: it look for me that you are looking special webmaster stuff, which would be better on [webmaster.se] which would be more specific if I understood it the point of view